# Form = Form = Form, what does statement do?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have never run across this type of statement before, can anyone enlighten me on its function.

```
Form = CardForm = MainForm;
```

This is a desktop app (which I am new to desktop apps in general)

Thanks

Comment: It's the assigment operator:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691314(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks everybody, that is what I thought, but I had never seen it coded that way.  Wanted to make sure there wasn't anything special about the statement.

Comment: You should really take the time to learn more standard naming conventions.  That code looks like a bunch of class names, not a bunch of variables.

Comment: @Servy well they are classes and this is an app I took over from someone who was fired - so tell him that..  :)

Comment: @BuddyMurphy If they are class names and not variables then the code won't compile.

Comment: @BuddyMurphy Then they're not referring to class names, they're variables.

Comment: @Servy CardForm is a variable of type MainForm and Form is a variable also - I stand corrected.  Like I said above I am brand new to this codebase and winforms.

Comment: @BuddyMurphy - This sort of thing isn't atypical its not all that strange.

Comment: @Ramhound Now that I see they are variables I agree, when I first asked I thought they were the actual Form classes.  But having said that I had not seen the a = b = c statement design before and it threw me off a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Form`, `CardForm`, and `MainForm` are variables...

It's 2 assignment operators, and assignment operators are unique in that they are evaluated from right to left.

first it sets `CardForm` to `MainForm` and then it sets `Form` to the result of `CardForm = MainForm`

Comment: Assignment *expressions* -- not statements -- are *evaluated* left to right, the same as all C# expressions. The *side effects* of the assignment operators take effect right to left. You can demonstrate that assignment is evaluated left to right easily: `class C { C M() { Console.WL(1); return this; } C N() { Console.WL(2); return this; } int P { get { Console.WL(3); return 4; } set { Console.WL(5); } }` and then do `c.M().P = c.N().P` and you will of course see that `M()` is executed before `N()` because assignment is, like all operators, evaluated left to right.

Comment: The *side effect* of the assignments happen as you say, right to left. Obviously the *assignment* cannot happen until after *both sides* are evaluated, so the assignment happens *after* the evaluation of the right. But the *evaluation of the operands* is left to right. Many people make this mistake, including people who write books about it.

Comment: Summing up, if you have `x = y = z` then the order of operations is first x is evaluated, then y, then z, then the assignment of z to y happens, then the value that was assigned to y is assigned to x. (Note that this is not necessarily the value of y!  y could be volatile and varying on another thread. or y could be a write-only property that has no value! There is *no read of y* here.) So once again: operands, left to right. Side effects of assignments, right to left.

Comment: @EricLippert you might want to tell that to the guys at MSDN  `"When two or more operators that have the same precedence are present in an expression, they are evaluated based on associativity. Left-associative operators are evaluated in order from left to right. For example, x * y / z is evaluated as (x * y) / z. Right-associative operators are evaluated in order from right to left. For example, the assignment operator is right associative. If it were not, the following code would result in an error."` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173145.aspx

Comment: Well, to be fair, the rest of that documentation clearly says that it is the *operators* that are evaluated in precedence/associativity order, not the *operands*. But I agree that this paragraph is confusingly worded. I'll mention it to the documentation manager.

Comment: @EricLippert to be more clear, I didn't intend to suggest anything about which order the operands were evaluated before any assignment actually happens.  I only intended to say that `y = z` gets evaluated before `x = *result of y=z*`  Sorry if i used the wrong terminology

Answer (score 17):

So far all of the answers contain subtle errors.  Let me set the record straight here.

The semantics of a chained assignment expression of the form

```
x = y = z
```

are:

- First expressions x, y and z are evaluated and their side effects, if any, are produced, in that order.
- Second, the value produced by evaluating z is converted to the type associated with expression y. Call this value z1.  Note that this might not be the value of z; a conversion may be involved.
- Third, the side effects of assigning z1 to y are performed.
- Fourth, z1 is converted to the type associated with expression x. Call this value z2. Again, z2 need not be the same as z1 or z.
- Fifth, z2 is assigned to x.

Summing up, this has the semantics of:

```
side effects of x
side effects of y
side effects of z
z1 = value of z converted to type of y
y = z1 
z2 = value of z1 converted to type of x
x = z2
```

Some of the other answers are trying to tell you that the semantics of `x = y = z;` are simply those of `y = z; x = y;` which is **completely wrong**. In that program the side effects of y and z happen *before* those of x, and in that program, *y is read from*. Neither of those are true in `x = y = z;`.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, as well as many other languages, the act of assigning a value to a variable returns a value itself.  This is called the *logical value* (or l-value) of an expression.

Suppose you wanted to set five variables:

```
int a, b, c, d, e;
```

To the number 5.  You could do:

```
a = b = c = d = e = 5;
```

The expression `e = 5` has a value of `5`, which will be set to `d`.  `d = 5` has a value of `5`, which will be set to `c`.  `c = 5` has a value of `5`, which will be set to `b`.  `b = 5` has a value of `5`, which will be set to `a`.  `a` will then be set to `5`.

As we don't know the types of `Card`, `CardForm` and `MainForm`, we can't tell you exactly what your code will do, as types can define implicit conversions, and an overridden assignment operator can return any value it feels like (of that type of course).

The expression:

```
CardForm = MainForm
```

Has a *logical value* of whatever ends up being assigned to `CardForm`.  Most likely, `CardForm` will be set to the value of `MainForm`, and that expression itself will return the *new* value of `CardForm`, which will then be set to `Form`.

Comment: That expression will result in *the value that was assigned to CardForm* which is not necessarily the value of *MainForm*. There could have been a user-defined conversion in there.

Comment: @EricLippert - Yea that statement kinda bugged me after I posted the answer.  But I couldn't think of a better way to explain that wouldn't make the answer more difficult to understand.

Comment: I notice that your final paragraph is the first one in this answer to actually correctly state the semantics of the assignment operator.

Comment: @EricLippert - Yea made a few updates to make this answer more *Eric Lippert Approved*

Answer (score 1):

Given `Form`, `CardForm` and `MainForm` are actually *variables*, though unlikely due to naming conventions recommend them to be in camelCase:

The `=` operator can be used transitively, thus this statement is equivalent to (quite roughly, for details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931435/17713 and comments!):

```
CardForm = MainForm;
Form = MainForm;
```

Note that `=` is *right-operative* (assignment order).

`=` cannot be overloaded in C#. Therefore is must be an assignment and there's no desktop-application-specific aspect of this line.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx

Comment: It is *not* equivalent to this. In the original form, `CardForm` is never read. In your allegedly equivalent form, it *is* read. If `CardForm` is a perfectly ordinary local variable then your statement is true but there are a number of ways in which it could be untrue; for example, it could be a volatile field and still be a variable. No read fence is introduced on CardForm in that case.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you for pointing this out. After rereading the documentation and the accepted answer + comments I corrected my "equivalent" code. It is now better, isn't it?